# Why is rest of function code cleared when firing window.location.reload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to begin counting the current session when the user has logged in. Because I store user details in sessionStorage, I need to do a location.reload in order for API-requests to be able to access the token in sessionStorage. The problem is that once I do the reload, the remaining code in the function is cleared, or neglected. I tried consol logging and it shows for about half a second then the console is cleared. How come, and how might I go about to still fire my setTimeout function and make it persist?

```
loginUser: function(username, password) {
    var loginDetails = {"username": username, "password": password};
    return loginResource.save({}, loginDetails).$promise.then(function(response){
        var user = {
            name: username,
            token: response.token,
        }
        sessionStorage.user = angular.toJson(user);
        $window.location.reload();
    })
    .catch(function(reason) {
        console.warn("Failed login", reason);
        throw reason;
    });
},

beginCountdown: function() {
    console.log('begin');
    setTimeout(function(){
        sessionStorage.removeItem('user');
        $window.location.reload();
    }, 3000)
},
```

Comment: if you reload the page then it is the normal behaviour.... you can move the reload later in your script if this is applicable for you

Comment: You don't need to reload the page when using `sessionStorage` as it's a synchronous operation (as far as I'm aware - certainly `localStorage` is) - your code can reference the stored data immediately after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because I store user details in sessionStorage, I need to do a location.reload in order for API-requests to be able to access the token in sessionStorage.

[That isn't true](https://jsbin.com/gaqacaxiwi/1/edit?js,console).

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
let data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
console.log(data);
```

… shows the data stored in line 1 and retrieved in line 2.

> once I do the reload, the remaining code in the function is cleared, or neglected.

The page is the environment in which your JavaScript runs in.

Reloading the page is equivalent to rebooting the computer and wondering why a Windows application doesn't maintain its state. It's *possible* to write a program in JS which saves it's state and reloads it when it is opened again, but you don't seem to be doing that.

Don't reload the page. Address the real problem. (Which is most likely that you are reading data from session storage when you load the JavaScript program, and then only writing updates to session storage and not to the variables where you are keeping the copy of that data you are working with.)

Comment: Then how do I make my JavaScript depending on sessionStorage values update once sessionStorage's been populated with new values?

Comment: You update whatever it is that the program is looking at to get the data *as well as the stored versions*.

Comment: I see, but is there some way to update whole views and controllers instead of having to update each and every reference to sessionStorage? I'm referencing to sessionStorage throughout my whole application.

Comment: "I'm referencing to sessionStorage throughout my whole application." — Restructure the application so each part of it doesn't pull data from the same source independently.